# PropertyNotFoundException: Unable to locate property

Tags: hibernate, jpa, named-query

I have the following namedQuery:

```
SELECT sr.*
FROM Sr sr
INNER JOIN sr.unitBinds srUnitBind
INNER JOIN srUnitBind.unit su
INNER JOIN sr.provBinds srProvBind
INNER JOIN srProvBind.prov prov
INNER JOIN prov.provActs provActs
LEFT JOIN provActs.ranges rngs
INNER JOIN rngs.value rngsValue
INNER JOIN rngsValue.value rngsValueCSV
INNER JOIN rngsValueCSV.ce rngsCe
AND rngsCe.code = :priority
```

Where "rngsValue.value" is an Entity represented by an Abstract class. This class is extended by many classes, and I want to join only with one of them. With the namedQuery in this form, I have this error:

> org.hibernate.PropertyNotFoundException: Unable to locate property
>   named ce

Because Hibernate try to do join with all classes extending that abstract class, and not only one I am interested in, and not all classes contains the "ce" field.
How can I solve?

Answer (score 0):

For downcasting use JPQL function `treat()`

```
JOIN TREAT(rngsValueCSV AS SubClass) s
JOIN s.ce rngsCe
```